# Запятая после того, как мы убираем союз

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, выбор-варианта

*Ты постоянно говоришь, **что** он виновен в этом*.
Остается ли запятая в данном предложении после того, как мы опускаем союз "что"?

Answer (score 1):

*Ты постоянно говоришь, что он виновен в этом.*
Это сложноподчиненое предложение с косвенной речью. Она оформлена в виде придаточного предложения.

При опускании союза "что" я вижу три возможных варианта пунктуации.

**А.** Слова "он виновен в этом" являются членом бессоюзного сложного предложения (ставим двоеточие):
**Ты постоянно говоришь: он виновен в этом.**

Что-то, мама, ты часто повторяешь: в моем доме... [Анатолий Ким. Белка (1984)]

**Б.** Слова "он виновен в этом" входят в предложение в качестве цитаты (берем их в кавычки, двоеточие не ставим):
**Ты постоянно говоришь «он виновен в этом».**

― Давай потом. Не хочу я сейчас петь. ― Ты всегда говоришь «потом». Теперь пой, ну! [И. C. Богатырева. Вернуться в Итаку (2008)]

**В.** Слова "он виновен в этом" оформляются как прямая речь (двоеточие, кавычки, заглавная буква):
**Ты постоянно говоришь: «Он виновен в этом».**

*Ты уверенно говоришь: «Я люблю его, и так будет всегда!»* (Н. Толстая)

Запятой здесь быть не может.

[Косвенная речь](http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-589.shtml#book_page_top)